# How to see fully evaluated preprocessed output from gcc

Tags: c

I know the option `-E` enables the proprocessed output from a `c` source file. But I want further to have the macros fully evaluated.

As a trivial example, in the following snippet,

```
# define P(n) n, n^1, n^1, n
const bool array[4] = {P(0)};
```

I want to see the exact values of elements in array[4]. But the `-E` output only shows `0, 0^1, 0^1, 0` etc. So how to make it to show `0, 1, 1, 0` in fully evaluated form here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood the role of the preprocessor. The preprocessor *expands* macros. `0, 0^1, 0^1, 0` is as fully expanded as possible. From there it's up to the next stage of compilation to interpret the numerical expressions. The next stage at which you can see the output for gcc is the generation of assembly code for which you can use `gcc -S`.

Answer (score 1):

That is its fully evaluated form.  The preprocessor doesn't do constant-folding, the compiler does.

Comment: Oh, I guess I was asking how to get constant-folding in addition to preprocessing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not at the preprocessing stage, you can go to the assembly code and find it there.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But ideally I still want it to be in the array assignment form. Looks like output from `-S` gives me a column here.

Answer (score 0):

The output you got is the fully preprocessed code. What you want is made during compilation.